# How to create a DGV column displaying a property from partial class?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, partial-classes

I'm writing a winforms application in C# (.NET 4.0, using EntityFramework).

I wanted to add a calculated property to an entity, which I did using a partial class. I can access new property from code, but not from designer (datasource, edmx, datagridview, ...). My datagridview is bound to a entity binding source (e.g. employeeBindingSource).

I want to add my calculated property (from partial class) to datagridview as a read-only column. The only solution that I found so far is way to messy for me ( [Properties in partial class not appearing in Data Sources window!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264074/properties-in-partial-class-not-appearing-in-data-sources-window) ). I'd much rather programmatically add the column.

How should I approach this?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to normally design the datagridview in designer, as much as possible (all columns except for those from partial classes). Then in my usercontrol (or form or whatever you have) constructor:

```
//in constructor
datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Then in in my load event of my usercontrol I hide unwanted columns that I got because I set dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true; And also modify header text (or whatever you need) of the column from partial class property.

```
//load event
 employeeDataGridView.Columns[11].Visible = false;
 employeeDataGridView.Columns[12].HeaderText = "Partial class prop";
```

I hope it will help someone.